# push_back using Thrust library

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, thrust

Is it possible to use push_back with Thrust library? and what about a vector of vectors? I would like to use in the GPU what in the CPu is:

```
 vector< vector<int> > MyVector( 100 );
 ...
 MyVector[i].push_back(j);
```

Is there a way to use it like for example:

```
thrust::device_vector<thrust::device_vector<int>> d_vec(4);
```

and what about creating an array of device_vectors? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, `thrust::device_vector` has a `push_back` method just like a `std::vector`.
2. No, it is not possible to have a `device_vector` containing `device_vectors`. If you need that sort of functionality in thrust I would recommend looking at `thrust::zip_iterator` which can provide "array of structures" like access to a series of distinct vectors or iterators.

Comment: What I want is access to a `device_vector dv` in this fashion: `dv[i][j`]

Comment: @Manolete: I don't believe that is possible.

Comment: But you could do dv[i*width + j].